# How change Navigation Bar title when using Expo and <Tabs>?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

Env

- Expo 5.4.9
- Expo Router 2.0.0
- React Navigation 6.0.2
- React Native 0.72.3

Project structure:

- auth/_layout.tsx (Tab)
- auth/current.tsx
- auth/... (other tabs as components)
- _layout.tsx (Stack)
- index.tsx (redirects to login)
- login.tsx (redirects to auth/current)

**File auth/_layout.tsx**

Tried:

1. Set **options.title** and **options.headerTitle** in <Tabs.Screen>:

```
<Tabs>
   <Tabs.Screen
      name="current"
      options={{
         title: 'In Progress',
         headerTitle: 'In Progress',
         tabBarLabel: 'In Progress',          
      }}
   />
   ...
</Tabs>
```

2. Set **navigationOptions.title** in  component:

```
<Tabs
   navigationOptions={{
     title:'In Progress'
   }}
>
   <Tabs.Screen name="current" .../>
    ...
</Tabs>
```

3. Set **screenOptions.title** and **screenOptions.headerTitle** in   component:

```
<Tabs
   screenOptions={{
     title:'In Progress',
     headerTitle: 'In Progress'
   }}
>
   <Tabs.Screen name="current" .../>
    ...
</Tabs>
```

**File auth/current.tsx**

4. Use **navigation.setOptions** inside screen component:

```
function CurrentScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: 'In Progress',
    });
  }, [navigation]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>In Progress</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

5. Set **Screen.navigationOptions.title**:

```
function CurrentScreen() {
   ...
}

CurrentScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'My Title'
};

export default CurrentScreen;
```

Each tab points to a .tsx file that implements a Screen.
No matter what I do, **it alwas display the route name** in navigation bar. I am able to change the header text, but I cant change the navigation bar text.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you didn't really give enough code, so I'm going to base my answer off a couple of assumptions.

The first is that you have a StackComponent nested in a TabsComponent. What I mean is each of your tabs is a stack.

The reason I made this assumption is because it looks like you have to headers. One from the Tabs and one from the Stack component. Both of which have a header.

To remove this, which ever stack has the name "auth", put headerShown = false in the options.

So your Tabs component should look like this

```
<Tabs.Navigator
      initialRouteName="In Progress"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
    <Tabs.Screen name={'In Progress} /> //You didn't provide your element so I assumed it was a Stack Navigator.
    {...rest}
</Tabs.Navigator>
```

The rest of the code you provided seems as if it should work fine at first glance. Which is why I believe you just need to hide a header.

Comment: Thank you and sorry if I wasnt clear enough. I did some changes in the question to make it more clear. Adding headerShown: false to <Tabs.Navigator> screenOptions made the header disappear ("In Progress" header in the image), but the navigation bar still displaying the "auth" text.

Comment: Is this the only navigator you have? Where do you have a navigator or screen named auth? that is where you need to set headerShown as false. There still isn't enough context for me to truly understand. Do you have a repo available?

If this is the only navigator you have in your app, I'm not sure what would make this happen. If you're using vscode. search "auth" and see if you can find where that header is. That is where you need to either set headerShown false or use a useEffect to update the title.

Comment: Yes, there is a root navigator (stack). I added headerShown: false to him and the "auth" header has gone. I'm pretty confused about the difference between a header and a navigation bar, some times it seems to be the same thing (as I added headerShown: false and its is gone) and sometimes not.

Comment: Looking at the documentation now it seems pretty clear to me that navigation bar doesnt exist, just header. The backbutton is shown at the header, so I guess my mistake was thinking them as two distinct things.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I didn't even realize you were calling it that. I could have noticed that then. But yes, it's very annoying but I understand why it's there because sometimes you need it and not the header that says "In Progress" like an app I'm currently building.